# Func<> with 2 output values

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, func

Is it somehow possible to create a function that has 2 output values?

I need a way to get 2 properties from an object, preferably by expression because of <strike>ease of use.</strike> using it along with a query provider to select multiple fields.

```
protected Expression<Func<T, TProperty1, TProperty2>> Select2Properties { get; set; }

public MyClass(Expression<Func<T, TProperty1, TProperty2>> selector) {
   Select2Properties = selector;
}

// desired usage (pseudo)
x => (x.Property1, x.Property);
```

I know this is complete rubbish, but any other solution (e.g. requiring 2 expression property selectors or requiring a tuple) results in sometimes unreadable constructor calls, especially when I require more than 2 properties:

```
x => x.Property1, x => x.Property2, x => x.Property3, x => x.Property4
// or 
x => Tuple.Create(x.Property1, x.Property2, x.Property3, x.Property4)
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To select out two properties from a selector you can use an anonymous type, if you don't like the syntax of a `Tuple`:

```
x => new { x.Property1, x.Property };
```

If that isn't feasible in context (generally because the type needs to be used outside of the scope of where it is defined) then you should simply be creating named types to select out of your selectors when you wish to select out multiple values.

Answer (score 4):

`Func<...>` only has regular parameters. You can, however, create your own delegate type:

```
delegate bool Foo(string s, out int i, out char c);
```

Obviously mix any way you want... However: you cannot mix that with `Expression`, at least not via the C# compiler's expression tree generator:

> An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator
>
> An expression tree lambda may not contain an out or ref parameter
>
> A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

The other option is to take parameters that have mutable properties. For example:

```
delegate bool Foo(SomeArgs args);
class SomeArgs {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Count {get;set;}
    public char Whatever {get;set;}
}
```

Now implementations can simply *change the properties of the parameter*.

Comment: The use of expressions indicates that this code is probably used by a query provider, making this almost certainly not a feasible option.

Comment: @Servy yes, it won't work well with a query provider; as per my edit a moment ago , it doesn't play nicely with `Expression`.

Comment: @Servy Yes, the expression will be pushed into a specification which then will by applied onto a IQueryable in order to find a entry which 2 properties that equal 2 passed arguments. So yeah, I need a Expression.